# How to schedule workflow in Luigi?

Tags: python, luigi

I am able to instantaneously execute a pipeline/workflow in `luigi` using the following:

```
luigi --module mypipeline mypipeline --local-scheduler
```

But how can I add a schedule to it, for example executing it every 10 days?

I wasn't able to find scheduler examples or applicable sample code in the [documentation](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/central_scheduler.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Luigi does not include its own triggering, so you have to rely on an external scheduler such as crontab to actually trigger the workflows.

For details, please refer to [this section of the docs](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/execution_model.html#triggering-tasks)